# linq sql error : the text data type cannot be selected as distinct because it is not comparable

Tags: linq

I want to select all questions from the questions table that haven't been included already for a particular quiz.
My question is why does the below code fail with the message :

**The text data type cannot be selected as DISTINCT because it is not comparable.
The data types text and text are incompatible in the is operator.**

```
var allQuestions = from q in my.Questions
                        select new
                        {
                            Select = new Boolean(),
                            Id = q.QuestionId,
                            QuestionName = q.Name,
                            QuestionText = q.Text,
                            Topic = q.Topic.Title
                        };

        var currentQuestions = from cq in my.QuizQuestions
                            where cq.Quiz.quizId == quizId
                            select new
                            {
                                Select = new Boolean(),
                                Id = cq.Questions.QuestionId,
                                QuestionName = cq.Questions.Name,
                                QuestionText = cq.Questions.Text,
                                Topic = cq.Questions.Topic.Title
                            };
var selectQuestions = allQuestions.Except(currentQuestions);
```

Where as this works fine:

```
 var allQuestions = (from q in my.Questions
                        select new
                        {
                            Select = new Boolean(),
                            Id = q.QuestionId,
                            QuestionName = q.Name,
                            QuestionText = q.Text,
                            Topic = q.Topic.Title
                        }).ToList();

        var currentQuestions = (from cq in my.QuizQuestions
                            where cq.Quiz.quizId == quizId
                            select new
                            {
                                Select = new Boolean(),
                                Id = cq.Questions.QuestionId,
                                QuestionName = cq.Questions.Name,
                                QuestionText = cq.Questions.Text,
                                Topic = cq.Questions.Topic.Title
                            }).ToList();


        int allquestionsCount = allQuestions.Count();
        for (int i = allquestionsCount; i < 0; i--)
        {
            foreach(var question in currentQuestions){
                if (question.Id.Equals(allQuestions.ElementAt(i - 1).Id))
                {
                    allQuestions.RemoveAt(i - 1);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is really a SQL question rather than a LINQ question, other than the fact that an `Except` LINQ call apparently ends up translated as a `DISTINCT` clause in SQL.

You could get LINQ to Objects to do the "except" part for you:

```
var allQuestions = // code as before in first example
var currentQuestions = // code as before in first example
var selectQuestions = allQuestions.AsEnumerable()
                                  .Except(currentQuestions);
```

The call to `AsEnumerable` just forces it to do the subsequent operations in-process with LINQ to Objects instead of converting it all into a SQL query.

Obviously that's pretty inefficient, but it's better than the potentially O(n^3) loop you've got at the moment :)

A [search for the error message](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q="The+text+data+type+cannot+be+selected+as+DISTINCT+because+it+is+not+comparable") (first part) gives some potentially helpful results on the SQL side though. I suggest you log the SQL being generated, then examine it and read those hits - they may suggest ways of altering your schema to allow it all to be done in the database.

Comment: Thanks Jon, that works. I have a similar query that works fine for another table. I think in this case the issue is with the datatype of the questiontext field.It is of type 'text'.

Comment: will test my assumption later.Thanks again.

Comment: Indeed - that's why it's worth looking at the SQL generated. I suspect that will explain why your other query works. There may be some way of altering the schema to make it work for text columns - I don't know, to be honest.